# Symfony 2 doctrine error

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to count my user's who are from Ukraine but i have a error.

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 192 near 'Ukraine GROUP': Error: 'Ukraine' is not defined.
500 Internal Server Error - QueryException
```

How i understand a problem is in how i enter a Ukraine value.

```
public function Action(){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();        
    $qb->add('select', 'count(user.id) as recount, ur.country, ur.year, ur.month, ur.day')  
        ->add('from','CobaCoreBundle:User ur')
        ->add('where', $qb->expr()->andx(
            'ur.date <= :end',
            'ur.date >= :start',
            'ur.country = Ukraine'
        ))
        ->setParameter('start',$period['fromd'])
        ->setParameter('end', $period['tod']);
    $qb->add('groupBy','ur.year, ur.month, ur.day');


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal value should be enclosed in speech marks:

```
'ur.country = "Ukraine"'
```

Comment: I am not sure if you have to use single quotes here, never tried before, doctrine might not be able to handle them. If this does not work, change the whole string to `"ur.country = 'Ukraine'"`.

Comment: Double quotes work with mysql but I guess they may not with doctrine